# How to vertically and horizontally centre images within a javascript slideshow?

Tags: css

I am trying to vertically and horizontally centre images within a javascript slideshow, however, I cannot figure out how to make this work,

I have tried display: inline-block with vertical-align: center; but it wont work

Any suggestions?

CSS

```
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vh;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.slideshow-container img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="001%20(1).jpg" onclick="plusSlides(1)">

  </div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="001%20(1).jpg" onclick="plusSlides(1)">

  </div>

<div class="nextprevious">
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#8592;</a>

  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#8594;</a>
  <div class="numbertext"><span>003</span> / <span>003</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out `display: flex`, and `justify-content: center;` and `align-content: center;` properties.

```
.slideshow-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mySlides {
  margin: 0px auto; /* horizontal align center in div */
}
```